# Add new class to div with DOMDocument

Tags: php

I am beginner webdeveloper. I have this code:

```
$content = '<div class="textowaTrescTresc ">
        <p><strong>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of
                classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
                professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words,
                consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical
                literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of
                "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book
                is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem
                Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief,
                Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC,
                making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in
                Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and
                going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem
                Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good
                and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
                during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
                in section 1.10.32.</strong></p>



        <blockquote>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
            Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
            Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem
            Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
            source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes
            of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
            during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
            section 1.10.32.
        </blockquote>

        <p>xxxx<img alt="Description 2" src="1.jpg" style="height:560px; width:840px" class="dupa"
                data-label-class="label-class"></p>

        <h4>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
            Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
            Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem
            Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
            source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes
            of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
            during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
            section 1.10.32.</h4>

        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin
            literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
            Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem
            Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
            source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes
            of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
            during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
            section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece
            of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
            professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,
            from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
            undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
            (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
            ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
            comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>



        <p><img alt="this is super nice image with lablethis is super nice image with lable 2" src="2.jpg"
                style="height:560px; width:840px">

        </p>

        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin
            literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
            Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem
            Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
            source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes
            of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
            during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
            section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece
            of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
            professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,
            from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
            undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
            (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
            ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
            comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

        <p><img alt="this is super nice image with lable 3" src="3.jpg" style="height:478px; width:840px"></p>



        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin
            literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
            Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem
            Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
            source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes
            of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
            during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
            section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece
            of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
            professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur,
            from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
            undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
            (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
            ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..",
            comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical
            Latin
            literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at
            Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a
            Lorem
            Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
            undoubtable
            source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The
            Extremes
            of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very
            popular
            during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
            in
            section 1.10.32.Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a
            piece
            of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
            professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words,
            consectetur,
            from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
            the
            undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et
            Malorum"
            (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of
            ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet..",
            comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>

        <p><img alt="this is super nice image with lable 4" src="5.jpg" style="height:560px; width:840px">
        </p>

    </div>';



$content = html_entity_decode($content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $old_src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
    $tag->setAttribute('data-label-class', 'label-class');
    $tag->setAttribute('class', 'picla');
}

$content = $doc->saveHTML();

echo $content;
```

It's work fine, but I have 2 small problems:

1. If I already have a class in IMG - the current php code deletes the previous class and only adds a new one (picla). I wish they were both available (both old classes and picla).
2. I would like the .picla class to be added only when the image has an "alt" attribute. If it doesn't, don't add the .picla class.

How can I make it?

Please help me.

For example in string I have:

```
<img alt="Description 2" src="1.jpg" style="height:560px; width:840px" class="dupa" data-label-class="label-class">
```

After my php script I have:

```
<img alt="Description 2" src="1.jpg" style="height:560px; width:840px" class="picla" data-label-class="label-class"> .
```

The correct result is:

```
<img alt="Description 2" src="1.jpg" style="height:560px; width:840px" class="dupa picla" data-label-class="label-class">
```

(2 class)

Comment: You talk about altering the class for `<div>` and yet your code only picks up `<img>` elements.  Can you also remove a lot of the `<p>` elements in the example HTML unless they help show the problem.  Once reduced to a couple of tags which show what you want to alter, can you then show what the result should look like.

Comment: I update my first post

Comment: You can use [`hasAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.hasattribute.php) to check if `alt` is there without having to fetch it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add required checks for `alt` and `class` attributes:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    // get value of an `alt` attribute
    $alt = $tag->getAttribute('alt');
    
    if (!empty($alt)) {
        // get current class(es)
        $class = $tag->getAttribute('class');
        if (!empty($class)) {
            $class .= " picla";
        } else {
            $class = "picla";
        }
        $tag->setAttribute('class', $class);
    }
    // other code here
}
```

Simple fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/46Hra).

Comment: Not sure you need the else - *I would like the .picla class to be added only when the image has an "alt" attribute. **If it doesn't, don't add the .picla class**.*

Comment: I set just one class in else if alt attribute is not empty.